# How to extract body text using Scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this piece of code which basically should extract the body text of a given website:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'smm'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls =['http://www.jeffbullas.com/2014/12/19/10-ways-to-succeed-in-the-new-age-of-mobile-content-marketing/']
    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        item = SocialMediaItem()
        item['webKW'] = response.xpath('//body//p//text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

However, it seems to scrap nothing. I have tested the xpath expression using the same website on this online tool http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi and it does exacly what I need, so It must be a problem with Scrapy coding. Can you help?
Thanks!

Dani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you shared it is not complete. In any case you need to set up the allowed_domains to instruct the spider about domains to go.

Here it is a working example

```
class jeffbullasSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "jeffbullas"
    allowed_domains = ["jeffbullas.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://www.jeffbullas.com/2014/12/19/10-ways-to-succeed-in-the-new-age-of-mobile-content-marketing/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        print response.xpath('//body//p//text()').extract()
```

An excerpt of the output will be:

> 2014-12-23 12:05:52+0100 [jeffbullas] DEBUG: Crawled (200) http://www.jeffbullas.com/2014/12/19/10-ways-to-succeed-in-the-new-age-of-mobile-content-marketing/>
>   (referer: http://www.bing.com) [u"Jeffbullas's Blog", u'Internet
>   Marketing', u'Written ', u'by', u' ', u'Jeff Bullas', u'  - ', u'15
>   Comments', u'\n\t\t\t\tCategories: ', u'Content Marketing', u', ',
>   u'Mobile', u', ', u'mobile content marketing', u', ', u'Mobile
>   marketing', u' ', u'There is a seismic shift in media.', u'The old
>   guard is ignoring it and new upstarts are embracing it.\xa0The eyeball
>   domination that made TV \u201cthe\u201d media for the last 50+ years
>   is now moving online. Digital is doing to TV what television did to
>   print and radio. Disrupt and disturb.',

Comment: Thanks aberna! It's working. However, how can I get the text from all the paragraphs, not just the 1st one?

Comment: the code works for all the paragraphs. The output in the reply is an excerpt

Comment: You're right, I didn't check properly. Thanks again!